# PyArrow: Incrementally using ParquetWriter without keeping entire dataset in memory (large than memory parquet files)

Tags: python, parquet, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I'm trying to write a large parquet file onto disk (larger then memory). I naively thought I can be clever and use ParquetWriter and write_table to incrementally write a file, like this (POC):

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import pickle
import time

arrow_schema = pickle.load(open('schema.pickle', 'rb'))
rows_dataframe = pickle.load(open('rows.pickle', 'rb'))

output_file = 'test.parq'

with pq.ParquetWriter(
                output_file,
                arrow_schema,
                compression='snappy',
                allow_truncated_timestamps=True,
                version='2.0',  # Highest available schema
                data_page_version='2.0',  # Highest available schema
        ) as writer:
            for rows_dataframe in function_that_yields_data()
                writer.write_table(
                    pa.Table.from_pydict(
                            rows_dataframe,
                            arrow_schema
                    )
                )
```

But even though the I'm yielding chunks (like 10 000 rows in my case) and using `write_table` it's still keeping the entire dataset in memory.

Turns out ParquetWriter keeps the entire dataset in memory *while it incrementally writes to disk*.

Is there anyway to force the ParquetWriter to not keep the entire dataset in memory, or is it simply not possible for good reasons?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68375254/incrementally-writing-parquet-dataset-from-python

Answer (score 4):

Based on analysis from the [Arrow bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-10052) this is potentially caused by collection of metadata which can only be flushed when the file is closed.